# why application crashes when when using onConfigurationChanged function?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using onConfigurationChanged function to check orientation change on android 4.0.3 for showing two  different fragment on my project but when application runs in first position (landscape or portrait) related fragment does not show when I change the orientation related fragment shown but when I change it again application crashed.
here is my code:

```
FragmentManager     fragmentmanager     = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ragmentmanager.beginTransaction();


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment1);

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment2);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: what type of exception you're getting?

Comment: Put log of exception

Comment: And I think you dont deattach previous fragment and this is cause exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure you have declared `android:configChanges` attribute in your activity in manifest.

> When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called.

Thus you need to declare manifest attribute to make your Activity know that you are going to handle config changes by yourself:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" 
   android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

At second, you need to apply transaction **before** `onConfigurationChanged` since it is not called at launch - the reason you see nothing on application start.

At last, put the lines `FragmentManager     fragmentmanager     = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ragmentmanager.beginTransaction();`

inside the `OnConfigurationChange()` to avoid null pointer exception after garbage collection.

Comment: thank you my fault was using FragmentManager     fragmentmanager     = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ragmentmanager.beginTransaction();out of function but there is still a problem that in first of running application none of fragments is not shown . :(

Comment: on first launch do check if you are Portrait or Landscape and then apply transaction